# How do I convert a base64 encoded torrent info_hash to a magnet link info_hash? (Linux)

Tags: linux, base64, sha1, bittorrent, info-hash

I have a list of base64 encoded info_hashes such as:

```
GiQilvwxZ4LUpJ/NpVUv9f7tV8s=
```

But when I run `echo ... | base64 -d`, it doesn't give me the real infohash, but a bunch of gibberish block characters.

How do I get the real, info_hash that's usable in a magnet link, from a base64 encoded one?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The output is a 20 byte raw binary string. In a magnet link, the info_hash is hex encoded. (For legacy reasons, it may also be base32 encoded.) So you need to hex encode the output.

Comment: Thanks, found the unix command to do this.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1):

It required a hex conversion to base 32, here's the command:

```
echo GiQilvwxZ4LUpJ/NpVUv9f7tV8s=| base64 -d| xxd -l 32 -p
```

Comment: It should be hex encoded. Only for compatability with legacy existing links, some clients accept base32. http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0009.html

Comment: Can you please explain this? i need to do this using java.

Comment: You might be able to google and find some java Base64 classes that can do this conversion for you.